# Conjugate and dual representation

Tags: representation-theory

Came by from this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_representation

I am wondering if $\Pi$ a representation, then $\bar{\Pi}$ and dual of $\Pi$ are isomorphic representations.

I can see $\Pi$ and $\bar{\Pi}$ is naturally isomorphic as vector space, hence $\bar{\Pi}$ and the dual is isomorphic as vector space. However, it seems like the natural isomorphism is not a representation isomorphism. How do we deduce this?

Comment: A representation of *what*? If $\Pi$ is a representation of a finite group, or more generally a unitarizable representation of a group, then the dual of $\Pi$ is indeed isomorphic to the conjugate of $\Pi$.

Comment: @Stephen Say of finite group over the field of complex number. Then it holds? How do we see that? I tried to find an isom $f_1$ from the original to the conjugate and then compose it with the isom $f_2$ of original and the dual. But I failed to show $f_1$ is an isom between representations. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group, let $\Pi$ be a representation of $G$ on a finite-dimensional $\mathbf{C}$-vector space $V$. We will write simply $gv=\Pi(g)v$ for the action of $G$ on $V$ via $\Pi$. Suppose $V$ is equipped with a non-degenerate Hermitian form $(\cdot,\cdot)$. That is, $(v_1,v_2) \in \mathbf{C}$ is linear in $v_2$, satisfies $(v_2,v_1)=\overline{(v_1,v_2)}$, and for each $v_1 \in V$ there is some $v_2 \in V$ with $(v_1,v_2) \neq 0$. If in addition the form is compatible with the action of $G$ on $V$ in the sense that
$$(g v_1,g v_2)=(v_1,v_2) \quad \hbox{for all $g \in G$ and $v_1,v_2 \in V$}$$ then the map $v \mapsto (v,\cdot)$ defines a $G$-equivariant conjugate-linear isomorphism of $V$ onto the dual space $V^*$, or in other words an isomorphism from the conjugate of $\Pi$ to the dual of $\Pi$.

Here is one situation in which such a form is guaranteed to exist: if $G$ is a finite group (or more generally a compact topological group, where sums are replaced by integrals with respect to a Haar measure) then you can start with *any* positive-definite Hermitian form $(\cdot,\cdot)'$ on $V$ and produce a $G$-invariant positive definite Hermitian form by averaging over $G$,
$$(v_1,v_2):= \sum_{g \in G} (g v_1,gv_2)'.$$ Here we use that a sum of positive-definite forms is positive definite and hence non-degenerate.

Answer (score 0):

The dual representation of $\rho$ is generally not isomorphic to $\rho$. For instance, for each integer $n$ the group of complex numbers of absolute value $1$ has a one-dimensional representation $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}\to\mathrm e^{\mathrm in\phi}$, whose dual is the representation $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}\to\mathrm e^{-\mathrm in\phi}$. These two representations are not isomorphic unless $n=0$.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter might say what's wrong with the answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote (which you can see if you look at my profile: I have *never* downvoted anyone), but I suppose the reason is that the OP is asking about why the dual should be isomorphic to the *conjugate* of the representation, not the representation itself.

Comment: @Stephen: Ah, thanks! I misread the question.

Comment: @Stephen: Where in your profile can I see that your (non-existent) downvotes?

Comment: Everybody has a publicly available count of their votes on the user page. Click on the activity tag. You, for instance, have cast 6509 upvotes and 556 downvotes as of this writing.

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks! I'd never scrolled down that far on that page :-)